# Checking SQLite version from a file opened via Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT

Tags: android, sqlite, android-intent

People,
I'm having the problem described in this thread:
[android-could-not-open-database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18102394/android-could-not-open-database)

But my question is quite different because the file I'm trying to open is chosen via an Intent.

I have in my manifest the permissions set:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

And when I try to get the database:

```
int version = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(fi.getPath(), null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE).getVersion();
```

Where "fi.getPath()" content is "/document/6195" (The chosen file from "Downloads" folder)

I need this because I have implemented a backup/ restore feature where the user choses a backup file to overwrite a database, but this only can be done if the two databases have the same db version (obviously).

I could not find this situation, where a SQLite database is opened with an Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT.

The error I get is:

> unknown error (code 14): Could not open database

The code works in emulator, but not in my real device, what makes me think about a permission question, but not sure...

I would appreciate if anyone here once in life have read a SqLite file from external storage...

Thanx!

*as I don't have any reputation to create an answer...*

**EDITED (ANSWER):**

Note that the file used by the recovery validation procedure was the same chosen by the user. After hours I could figure out that this was the problem. My device didn't make use of an external storage and the downloaded files was stored internally. That was the difference between the device and emulator. Then, I changed my code to create a temporary file and fill its content with the content of the file grabbed by the user. This way, the file managed afterwards by the recovery component was located in the temp folder and no permission problem would happen. This is how the code looks like after the refactor:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case FILE_SELECT_CODE:
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                Uri uri = data.getData();
                try {
                    InputStream fileInputStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(data.getData());
                    File tempFile = File.createTempFile(uri.getLastPathSegment(), null, context.getCacheDir());

                    FileChannel originChannel = ((FileInputStream)fileInputStream).getChannel();
                    FileOutputStream destOutput = new FileOutputStream(tempFile);
                    FileChannel destChannel = destOutput.getChannel();
                    originChannel.transferTo(0, fileInputStream.available(), destChannel);

                    BackupFile file  = new BackupFile(new FileInputStream(tempFile), tempFile.getPath());
                    BackupData backupData = new SQLiteBackupData(context, file, new SQLiteBackupDataValidator(file));
                    DataSecurityEvent dataSecurityEvent = new SQLiteRecovery(backupData);
                    List<DataSecurityEvent> events = new ArrayList<DataSecurityEvent>(0);
                    events.add(dataSecurityEvent);
                    new BackupDataAsyncTask(context, events).execute();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    ToastOnMiddle.makeText(context, context.getString(R.string.recover_fail), 
                       Integer.parseInt(context.getString(R.string.app_toast_time))).show();
                } catch (BackupDataException bde) {
                    ToastOnMiddle.makeText(context, getExceptionMessageValue(bde.getMessage()), 
                       Integer.parseInt(context.getString(R.string.app_toast_time))).show();
                }
            }
            break;
    }
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

Note that I used FileChannel to fill the temp file with the selected file content.
I don't know exactly yet why this problem occurs when trying to create or open a SQLite database directly from an internal storage folder. If someone can explain in the comments below, I would be very glad! =)

**Lesson learned:** Do not get a database file from a file chooser intent and try to use it directly to create or open a SQLite database. You better off using a temporary file instead.

Comment: What you want to do?

Comment: I must overwrite the database of my app, swapping that file with another that was previously saved to the "Downloads" folder. But the file I choose to overwrite must be checked because of the version, that must be the same of the overwitten one.

Comment: The code works in emulator, but not in my real device, what makes me think about a permission question, but not sure...

Comment: Is your device has Marshmallow?

Comment: Nope. It's a Lollipop.

Comment: Do you get an error code when you try opening the file as a file?

Comment: No. I get no error handling the file. And thereby I can do set writeable to it:
`code` File fi = new File(file.getPath());
`code` fi.setWritable(true);

Comment: I managed to solve this problem but unfortunately I can't write an answer as StackOverflow has blocked my answers...
I will try to put here in the comment...

Comment: **SOLUTION:** Instead of using directly the file (selected by the user), first I create a copy of it in a temp file and use this copy to read the SqlLiteDatabase. The reason is apparently because my device do not make use of an external storage.
[More details here](http://www.saulojunior.com.br/2016/02/android-reading-sqlite-databases.html)

Comment: Please don't add 'solved' to your post title. Feel free to post an answer below to help future visitors, instead.

Comment: Well, as I wrote just above your comment, I don't have permission to answer. Maybe you could help me with this. Could you?